# Brake Lights Stay On

Tags: tail-lights, brake-booster

I attempted to replace my master cylinder and brake booster. Now my brake lights are stuck on. I recall a ratcheting sound after disconnecting the booster from the brake pedal. The brakes feel as if there is a normal amount of travel. I'm not sure what to do.

2014 jeep Wrangler unlimited Rubicon

Comment: Please add the year/make/model of the vehicle to your post. It's much more difficult to diagnose without that information.

Comment: So, did you find the source of the "ratcheting sound" and correct it?

Comment: @kyle_engineer, done.

Comment: @solar_mike, not yet.

Comment: @SolarMike, found it! When I disconnected the booster, the pedal was able to extend and hit the switch. This was the clicking/ratcheting sound I heard.

Comment: I don't know if my reply is too late or not but btw my suggestion is you can check the stopper and the brake lights switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in all cars there are certain switches on the pedals depending on the model and the accessories in the car. The brake pedal switch is a standard feature in all modern cars because it is used to be triggered when the brake pedal is pressed.

This switch is adjustable like the brake pedal height in the car. It is quite common after such job to be needed adjusting. I'm pretty sure you will find out how you can adjust it in your car, since you did brake master cylinder replacement on your own. After you finish, you need to have all 3 pedals on the same height, and the switch to be triggered after you slightly press the brake pedal.

Comment: Some cars have two brake switches...

Comment: I was able to pull the switch out and reset the brake lights. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshC. I'm glad I helped you my friend... You were lucky because that applies to most cars, however when you post questions it is generally great practice to give model and year information... :)